# How to solve "Runtime.ImportModuleError" No module named 'mysql' in AWS lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependencies

I'm testing Python script in Lambda, it gave me an error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'pythonfilename': No module named 'mysql'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

How can I fix this? When I tested the script locally I got the same error, but after I upgrade `pip` to 20.2.2 then `pip install mysql-connector` this error has been solved locally, how can I solve this issue in Lambda env? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying a function to AWS lambda you need to bundle your dependencies:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Lambda [custom layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) with your packages.

To check this solution I created such a layer and can **confirm that it works**.

The technique used includes **docker tool** described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

Thus for this question, I **verified it**  as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
boto3==1.14.49
mock==4.0.2
moto==1.3.14
mysql-connector-python==8.0.21
```

3. Run the following docker command:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r -9 mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console.
   Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.8`. The layer will
   by large, **about 48 MB**. Thus it would be a good idea to check if you
   really need all these packages.
6. Test the layer in lambda using the following lambda function:

```
import mysql

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(dir(mysql))
```

The function executes correctly:

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```